# Update table based on CTE

Tags: psycopg2

I have an update query as below:

```
WITH update_cte as (
        SELECT col1, col2, 
        daterange(col3, col4) as col5
        FROM temp_table
        )
        UPDATE my_table
        SET col5 = update_cte.col5
        FROM update_cte inner join my_table
        ON (update_cte.col1 = mytable.col1)
        AND (update_cte.col2 = mytable.col2)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
"Error: table name \"my_table\" specified more than once\n"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by specifying an alias in inner join.

```
 WITH update_cte as (
            SELECT col1, col2, 
            daterange(col3, col4) as col5
            FROM temp_table
            )
            UPDATE my_table
            SET col5 = update_cte.col5
            FROM update_cte inner join my_table as idr
            ON (update_cte.col1 = idr.col1)
            AND (update_cte.col2 = idr.col2)
```